# What is the mathematics behind the GAM prediction intervals?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, generalized-additive-model, prediction-interval

From the R `gam` function available in the `gam` and `mgcv` package there is the option to obtain the prediction intervals.

A fitted GAM model can be represented as $y=S_\lambda \beta$.

From this representation how can I get the prediction intervals in formula?